# Minimax python - how to efficiently find alternating max and mins in a tree

Tags: python, minimax

The following code I'm using to minimax a tree looks awful. Surely there is a way to simplify this and use a function instead of a int.MaxValue

```
if depth%2==1:
    min = 9999
    for child in currentRoot.children:
        if child.score < min:
            min = child.score
    currentRoot.score = min
else:
    max = -9999
    for child in currentRoot.children:
        if child.score > max:
            max = child.score
    currentRoot.score = max
return currentRoot.score
```

Comment: One idea I had was to negate the score at every level of the tree so I could always find the max, but that seems slightly tricky to get right since I could have all of them reversed and need to find mins depending on the depth of the leaves.

Comment: See linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980286/python-find-minimum-object-using-special-comparator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't use `min` and `max` for variable names as this shadows the built-in functions. Second, use these built-in functions!

You can use your current logic to pick out whether you want `min` or `max` and then pass a generator expression to access each child's score.

```
measure = min if depth % 2 else max
return measure(c.score for c in currentRoot.children)
```

Comment: Oh, much cleaner than mine. I feel like I was iteratively getting closer to something like that, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Also, if OP does need that default `-999` or `999` (if there are no children), could probably do `default = 999 if depth % 2 else -999` and then use that like `measure(c.score for c in root.children, default=default)` (I also just learned `min`/`max` have a `default` kw!)

Comment: @dwanderson That is cool! I do not need those defaults however. But I would like to know what the default is if I leave it blank

Comment: @Jared This leaves out the assignment so I'm using this answer with : current.score = measure(c.score for c in currentRoot.children); return current.score

Answer (score 0):

```
def findNewScore(isEven):
    if isEven:
        root.score = max([c.score for c in root.children] + [-999])
    else:
        root.score = min([c.score for c in root.children] + [999])
    return root.score
```

Or even just:

```
def findNewScore(isEven):
    s = sorted(c.score for score in root.children)
    if isEven:
        root.score = max([-999, s[-1]])
    else:
        root.score = min([999, s[0]])
    return root.score
```