# Python Find minimum object using special comparator

Tags: python, comparator

So I got [my question answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973944/minimax-python-how-to-efficiently-find-alternating-max-and-mins-in-a-tree/37974066#37974066) on how to find the minimum value, but what if I want the minimum object? Can we similarly simplify this code?

```
        min = 9999
        minChild = None
        for child in currentRoot.children:              
            if child.score < min:
                min = child.score
                minChild = child
            recurseWriteBook(child, depth+1)
```

Comment: Is your recursion broken? You're calling a `recurse...()` function, returning nothing, not declaring global variables, and not getting a return value from the function. You can remove a couple of lines by looking at minChild.score and not keeping `min` (a name you were advised not to use in your linked question, btw), but it's not clear if you can simplify all of it without seeing all of it. You can't trivially use `min()` on nested structures though.

Comment: No, everything is working, except I had to raise my min=9999 to 1<<31, but I guess I changed my function so it is no longer recursive, I am just writing moves to disk as I get deeper into the tree. Seemed simpler to do it going forwards since I don't need leaf nodes like I do when I minimax. If you're interested in the whole function it is here: http://pastebin.com/xVue2i5c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in function [min(iterable[, key])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...
>>>
>>> l = [Foo(2), Foo(1), Foo(3)]
>>>
>>>
>>> min_foo = min(l, key = lambda x: x.value)
>>>
>>> min_foo.value
1
```

You tell it which `key`/attribute to use to compare objects.

Answer (score 0):

You know your types (list/tuples) and how to adjust them, so you
can use technique like this:

```
list_min = [1,2,3,4] # list to demonstrate

m = lambda mn,lst: filter(lambda x: x <mn,lst) # get the minimum out of list

minimum = 3 # test value
print m(minimum,list_min)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer I selected plus the answer from my other question to use this:

```
minChild = min(currentRoot.children, key = lambda child: child.score)
```

Comment: Also had to make sure I still called my function to progress deeper into the tree.